# ASP.NET: Get milliseconds since 1/1/1970

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, date, utc

I have an ASP.NET, VB.NET Date, and I'm trying to get the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. I tried looking for a method in MSDN, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can subtract any two `DateTime` instances and get `TimeSpan` and `TotalMilliseconds` would give you total milliseconds. Sample below.

```
    DateTime dt1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;//DateTime.UtcNow for unix timestamp
    TimeSpan span = current - dt1970;
    Console.WriteLine(span.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

**one liner**

```
//DateTime.MinValue is 01/01/01 00:00 so add 1969 years. to get 1/1/1970
DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 58):

Starting with .NET 4.6, The method `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` provides a more accurate solution.

From `DateTimeOffset`:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

From `DateTime`:

```
new DateTimeOffset(dateTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=netframework-4.6#System_DateTimeOffset_ToUnixTimeMilliseconds

Comment: I love the `DateTimeOffset` solution! :)

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you can use the Ticks property and avoid construction of a temporary object:

```
long epochTime = (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000;
```

However, this isn't entirely

Reasoning:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
var temp = d.Ticks; // == 621355968000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This will provide the UNIX Epoch in milliseconds.
(Respects UTC time instead of your local time)

```
Split(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds(), ".", 2)(0)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the above 1 liner which is accepted as the answer because of the double datatype, C# adds the "." (Period) in between and it can cause issues when you take the string representation.