# What is the different between Refresh vs Putting URL and pressing enter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, http-headers

I have asp.net mvc application, when I use chrome it loads the home page (which has many .js links) it works fine.

but when I press F5 or refresh, it doesn't load all the .js (and more other things like .png even) links!

unless I click on the URL text box and then enter, it works fine with this.

in the console chrome shows: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

[image]

and the header title: Provisional headers are shown

in firefox nothing happens and the app works fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers handle caching differently. The only way to be certain that the resource will be loaded from the server each and every time is to address it by a different name. Personally with javascript files I use version numbers and increment this number each time i modify the contents to ensure the new version is loaded from the server instead of from cache. Such as

```
<script src="myLibrary_1.0116.js">
```

The other option is to keep the same JS file name and append a string to the url such as

```
<script src="myLibrary.js?version=1.0116">
```

Then if you absolutely want the script to load from the server EVERY time then you could use a script to append a random string to the end of your source name. Like such

```js
 var scriptsList=["script1.js","script2.js","script3.js"];

    function buildKey(){
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890";

        for( var i=0; i < 16; i++ )
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        return text;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
    for(i=0; i<scriptsList.length; i++)
      var s=[];
      s[i] = document.createElement("script");
      var sessionKey = buildKey();
      s[i].type = "text/javascript";
      s[i].src = scriptsList[i]+sessionKey;
      $("head").append(s[i]);
      
    }
```

```js
var gracePeriod=25*1000;


function isCached(){
  var currentTimeStamp= Date.now();
  var contentGeneratedTime=parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].getAttribute("generated-Time"));
  if(currentTimeStamp>contentGeneratedTime+gracePeriod)
    window.reload(true);
  }
```

```html
<html><body generated-Time="UNIXTIMESTAMP"></body></html>
```

This last function will require PHP or asp.net to set the timestamp on the body tag. The javascript will check to make sure that the document was generated within the last 25 seconds and if not will force a reload while discarding the cache.

```
long epochTime = (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000;
```

This will give you your UNIX timestamp in miliseconds in asp.net

Comment: but I am using Bundles, which change the name of the resource file each time

Comment: If the resource file changes then there is no way to load it from the cache. What may be happening is chrome is loading the entire HTML from cache. In which the Javascript appending the random string each time will be the best bet to force these resources to reload, however; you will also need a random string in your main url to prevent caching the HTML itself

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati please view edit. This new function will ensure your html is not cached. However this really isn't highly recommended as it will force your HTML, Images, JS, and CSS to load straight from the server each time. If this is a static site it will be a waste of bandwith.

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati did this work for you? If so please dont forget to select as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am using asp.net not php

Comment: Same concept. edited above to show the code in asp.net. Im not an asp programmer and took that line from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680375/asp-net-get-milliseconds-since-1-1-1970

Comment: I'm still not convinced that chrome uses the cache for html, because I already disabled the cache in developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on the title of the thread.
Pressing enter on the url in the address bar is the equivalent of navigating to the url for the first time but will load cached resources from any prior visits.

Pressing F5 reloads the page but will also attempt to retain any request made of the page upon accessing thus if you had submitted data to the page via a form and pressed F5 the browser should ask if you wish to resubmit the data which was submitted when accessing the page where as in this case if you pressed enter on the url the data would be lost.

If you press Ctrl+F5 on the page this would perform the same actions as F5 but in addition would ignore any local caching that had been performed and request a new copies of any resources loaded from the site e.g. it would request fresh copies of any images linked within the page rather than loading a local stored copy from the browser cache.

In addition there are variations of these conditions which will have an effect on each scenario for example if the page has a querystring (a url followed by ?[key]=[value]) then regardless of the method of page access (direct via enter on url or refresh) this data would be passed to the page also if the page uses an anchor tag in the url (# followed by a string e.g. #top) this would cause the page to navigate to that anchor regardless of the method of refresh but in both these cases the method of refresh would still effect resources being loaded from cache or pulled from the host as detailed in my above examples.

I know this doesn't resolve the additional questions asked but it will clarify the difference between navigation to a url, refreshing a page after first visit and forcing a full refresh of the page for anyone coming here for an answer to the post title question.